# Debate flagged Questions and Answers need clarification

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I faced situations like this answer: ["Whoever kills a person.."](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/29648/3466)  This one looks like create debate.

And a better example: [Is it halal in Islam to work as a web/graphics designer?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/29561/is-it-halal-in-islam-to-work-as-a-web-graphics-designer) Question and some answers( and deleted answers, like @saadet 's ; deleted by @goldPseudo) seems like create debate. However, this is a SE site and if you have resources to disprove claims made by original poster(OP), you should answer it.

There are different approaches to Islam, and every point of view should be represented on answers. This is the scientific way to approach. And it could be in different answers, because not everybody knows about ever point of view. Instead of deleting answer, debate like comments should be eliminated.  If I have resources I should able to add this resources to answer.

Another thing to add this, in this [question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/29561/is-it-halal-in-islam-to-work-as-a-web-graphics-designer) questioner claimed something like "..we know animal picture and others are not halal.." and ask questions based on this. However, OP doesn't prove his claim. If there is a way to say this is wrong, in one answer, this should be represented. We cant just accept every claim here without prove. It seems to me, if someone says "water is not exist on earth, and so i have to go to mars, tell me which way is?" and if i have a proof which shows water on earth, shouldn't i add this to answer? Yeah, I know he wants  to learn ways to mars. My answers irrelevant to last point of the question, but if question somehow start from wrong information, I should able to intercept and add information there.

Another example for this view is; if I ask question like "We know there are two Gods in Islam, can I worship to one mornings and other one to afternoon?" Users of this site shouldn't intercept my first believe then try to answer afterwards? I can't see any of benefits of this approach. Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 2):

I think the way to handle when you see a claim that is not a consensus view is to comment under the post and ask the OP to cite a reference for the claim and add an "according to X ..." clause to the claim. Not only this resolves the issue it also provides context that can help answer the question the OP has.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, Islam Stack Exchange a Q&A site. People ask questions, we answer those questions.

This may seem obvious, but I often feel that I need to reinforce it. Now, keeping that in mind, consider these two follow-ups:

- Does representing every point of view in an answer *help the questioner get his answer*?
- Does proving or disproving claims made in the question *help the questioner get his answer*?

Now I'll admit that, yes, sometimes they *do*. However, it is so so often the case that people arguing for the above are doing so for entirely the wrong reasons: Rather than out of any concern for helping the questioner himself get a useful answer, they are more interested in promoting their own theological point of view.

Just take a look on the Internet; there are *countless* Islamic fora out there which already encourage that sort of thing. Back-and-forth attempts to prove and disprove each others claims, often repeating the same arguments over and over ad-nauseum. In other words, *noise*: The people who have actual *questions* are more likely to end up *even more* confused afterwards.

The Stack Exchange model is explicitly designed to cut through all that: We're here to give people *answers*, not *noise*. In other words, we're here for the people who are tired of having to pick through pages and pages of arguing and conflicting opinions in order to find that one pure nugget of actual *answer*.

As part of that philosophy, yes if a question is asked under false assumptions, it *could* be useful to call that out and show the questioner the truth of things: That *will* help him toward a *useful* answer to his question. However, it is vitally important to know the difference between "false assumptions" and "difference of opinion".

We are open to *all* interpretations of Islam: So far as this site is concerned, that means any and every group that self-identifies *as* Muslim. So whereas your hypothetical "We know there are two Gods in Islam…" would (to the best of my knowledge) be factually untrue for *any* interpretation of Islam — and thus reasonable to correct the questioner on — the same cannot be said of "…animal picture and others are not halal…": There *are* well-known scholars and schools of jurisprudence that make exactly that claim, and there are many people who *follow* them.

And if a questioner is asking about something particular to the school/sect/interpretation he chooses to follow — be that a mainstream, a minority, or even a *fringe* interpretation — giving him a bunch of answers from other perspectives *does not help him at all*, and neither does "disproving" his beliefs. All that's really likely to do is convince him that Islam Stack Exchange is actually *not* a good place to find useful answers after all (which is sorta exactly *not* what we're going for here…)

As you say, we shouldn't just accept every claim here without proof, and nobody's asking you to. But just because the questioner is unwilling or unable to *prove* the interpretation of Islam that he chooses to believe (be that from  lack of interest or lack of knowledge) shouldn't preclude him from asking questions *about* it, and whether or not others happen to *agree* with him shouldn't stop him from being given the same respect as anyone else on this site.

Comment: Thanks for some clarifications. Your answer brings to my mind, SE sites generally gives opportunity to give all kind of answers. For example [this](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3332/does-this-sites-policy-against-debating-whos-right-mean-that-the-site-is-tea) One of answers mentions: "They read through the answers, and decide which one makes the most sense to them." 
So i am not here for sake of debate. I am here for sake of knowledge. Eliminating one of resources makes this site poorly constructed in compare to other SE sites.

Comment: I am suggesting that instead of eliminating the answer(which supported by resources), we should eliminate debate like comments on that answer.  I am not suggesting that opinion based answers should be included. When I come here, I want to see every perspective of Islam on a question. As far as I know SE sites for this purpose. Questioner will get his perspective of answer as well as others. If Islam includes this views, we should see these answers in a scientific way in here. As we always say this is not support site.We are here to show all perspective of "topic" (Islam)

Comment: @nim If you want an answer that covers every perspective of Islam, *just ask for it*; there's no reason to shoehorn all that information into other people's questions if they didn't ask for it at all. (I'd recommend going through the meta posts http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/a/1682/22 and http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/1595/22, as well as posts linked to those, for advice on how to get such to work under Stack Exchange).

Comment: Before asking this question, I read these topics and lots of other topics also. Thanks for reminding again. And yet i don't agree on some of your points. Your moderating on this site is not exactly same standart with other SE sites moderating. I find this interesting. Anyway thanks for your effort and your answers.

Comment: I now want to go found a bitheistuc version of Islam. ;)

Comment: @nim Arguably, if someone comes here to ask "What does *Group X* teach about *situation A*?" and you instead answer what Group Y teach, you haven't answered the question asked.

Comment: @TRiG Yes, I agree on answering question on perspective Group X. However, I can't see any harm on adding more resource on answer. If questioner claim something and show no proof, I should able to add my resources to answer as well